# chain async operations using native JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I've following two async operations and then final `onResult` and `onFault` defined. How can I chain following two async operations `getConnection` and then `select` and then finally calling `onResult` or `onFault`

**Edit** need help in promisifying following sequence.

```
    new Promise(this.getConnection)
        .then(this.select)
        .then(this.onResult)

getConnection: function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('get connection')
    if(database = common.model.connections.Sync.getConnection()) {
        database.transaction(function(transaction){
            resolve(transaction);
        });
    } else {
        reject("Connection Error");
    }
},

select: function(transaction) {
    console.log('select', transaction)
    var self = this;

    var query = "SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE key = 'schedule'";
    self.transaction.executeSql(query, [], function(transaction, resultSet){self.selectTransactionComplete(transaction, resultSet)}, function(){self.selectTransactionError()});
},

selectTransactionComplete: function(transaction, resultSet) {
    console.log('select transaction complete')
    if(resultSet.rows.length == 0) {
        this.onResult(false);
    } else if(new Date().getTime() - new Date(common.Config.getLastSync()).getTime() > resultSet.rows.item(0).value) {
        this.onResult(true);
    }
},

selectTransactionError: function(error) {console.log(this.constructor.NAME, this.selectSQL); console.log(error);},

onResult: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
},

onFault: function(info) {
    console.log(info)
}
```

Comment: You appear to be using promises like callbacks. Don’t; return them instead. `asyncAction`, for example, should either return a promise or pass two arguments (neither of which can throw directly) to `then`.

Comment: [**What is the deferred anti-pattern and how do I avoid it?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: removed asyncAction as it was out of the scope, how can I reach from `getConnection` to `onResult` call via these two async operations - `getConnection` & `select`, just like here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ (queueing async operations)

Comment: appreciate any help using written code in context of my example, I've gone through articles, understand single asyn but still stuck and confused for multiple queued async operations, I noticed `Promise.all` but not sure if this will work in my case

Comment: after reading couple of things, please review my attempt below in my answer, is this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @minitech I realized what you mean by using promises like callbacks, I revised my attempt in my answer below, however, there's an inherit problem with promises which is forcing me to not to use it in my already structured code, that is, let' say after `onResult` anywhere in my code if i have exception it's going to be suppressed, reason it's part of promise chain, however I want out of the chain and get into my normal coding routine but once I'm in promise, I'm in the chain, and any errors are silently ignored, to reproduce the issue inside `onResult` type `throw "error"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying couple of things, is this how it's supposed to be done? please review

```
    this.getConnection()
        .then(this.select, this.getConnectionError)
        .then(this.selectTransactionComplete, this.selectTransactionError)

getConnection: function() {
    console.log('get connection')

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        try {
            database = common.model.connections.Sync.getConnection();
            database.transaction(function(transaction){
                resolve(transaction);
            });
        } catch(error) {
            reject("Connection Error");
        }
    });

    return promise;
},

getConnectionError: function(info) {
    console.log("connectionError");
    this.onFault();
},

select: function(transaction) {
    console.log('select')
    var self = this;

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE key = 'schedule'";
        transaction.executeSql(query, [], function(transaction, resultSet){resolve(resultSet)}, function(error){reject(error)});
    });

    return promise;
},

selectTransactionComplete: function(resultSet) {
    console.log('selectTransactionComplete')

    /*if(resultSet.rows.length == 0) {
        this.onResult(false);
    } else if(new Date().getTime() - new Date(common.Config.getLastSync()).getTime() > resultSet.rows.item(0).value) {
        this.onResult(true);
    }*/
},

selectTransactionError: function(error) {
    console.log('selectTransactionError')
    //console.log(this.constructor.NAME, this.selectSQL);
    //console.log(error);
},

onResult: function(data) {
    console.log('onResult')
},

onFault: function(info) {
    console.log('onFault')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a promise library like [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), the way you would go about chaining the promises is as below;

```
getConnection: function() {
    var deferred = Q.Defer();
    console.log('get connection')

        try {
            database = common.model.connections.Sync.getConnection();
            database.transaction(function(transaction){
                deferred.resolve(transaction);
            });
        } catch(error) {
            deferred.reject("Connection Error");
        }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

when you call you would do something like below;

```
Q.when(getConnection)
.then(function(result){
 // handle success or resolve
}, function(error){
 // handle rejection.
};
```

Also I suggest reading the [common js promises specification](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises)

Comment: thanks Jerome for the code, however, I'm looking to do the same in native JavaScript promise

Comment: The `Q.when` is redundant (just call getConnection). Moreover if you use Q.Promise (in new versions of Q) instead of deferreds you won't need to type that try/catch it'll do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. May I ask why you want to do vanilla JS when there are good libs implemented for this?